# Select item from database based on date range

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database of events, and I need to be able to show an event occuring 'today'. The events have start and end dates in the format: Y-m-d h:i:s

How would I do this? I've tried queries along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_events 
WHERE start>='2009-11-03 16:00:00' 
and end<='2009-11-03 16:00:00'
```

To no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What format is the data stored in your `start` and `end` columns? What datatype are those columns?

Comment: The fields are datetime as "Y-m-d h:i:s" For example, one event is: START 2009-11-02 12:00:00 / END 2009-11-09 11:59:59

Preferably I would be able to select these down to the second... None of the solutions below work correctly so far.

Comment: is there a reason you don't have quotes around the datetime in your query?  e.g. `'2009-11-03 16:00:00'`

Comment: Haha, yes, I forgot to type them in, I'll do that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried casting the datetime string to type "datetime" ?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl_events 
WHERE 
        start >= CAST('2009-11-03 16:00:00' AS DATETIME)
    AND end   <= CAST('2009-11-03 16:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Or, for that matter, what's wrong with using a function like `NOW()` or a keyword like `CURRENT_TIME`,`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`,`CURRENT_DATE`?

For Exmaple:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl_events
WHERE
        start >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    AND end   <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

EDIT: Andy-Score may be on to something with the between operator and reserved words, something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl_events
WHERE
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
```

Comment: Thank you! I had completely forgotten about the between operator..!

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the dates and not the times, this will work for 'today'

```
select * from tbl_events where start >= curdate() and end < curdate() + 1
```

If you want to specify the dates and times, this will work:

```
select * from tbl_events 
where start >= '2009-11-03 08:00:00' and end <= '2009-11-03 16:00:00'
```

Comment: Hi tvor - your later option is what I'm after, being able to specify the date and time, but the query doesn't work (it's the same as mine above)

Answer (score 0):

You want to select events that occurred on this day, not at this precise second, right?  Hence your `WHERE` clause should look more like `start = '2009-11-03'`.

Comment: Preferably narrowed down to time as well, but thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it may now work, could be that end is a restricted word (or something of that sort)

[mysql.com begin-end info page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html)

you may want to change your database field names to be event_start and event_end, which will hopefully fix the problem, though I could be talking rubbish.

Also if it helps at all you can use the following method to get dates from a range

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_event WHERE event_start BETWEEN (start_date) AND (end_date)
```

This only looks at one field, in this case event_start, but means that if you want to get range of events which have a start date between a set range you can.

Comment: also, stealing someone else's comment, it's probably a good idea to surround your date range parameters in ' 's (single quotes) as it'll help to contain the data being passed in the query.

Comment: Thank you for all of your assistance, 'between' did the trick, I'd completely forgotten about that operator!

Comment: no worries, have only recently started using it properly myself, so was fresh in my mind, but very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as ce from estudantes where nascimento between DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ),INTERVAL 18 YEAR) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ),INTERVAL 25 YEAR)
```